# Java Garbage Collection increases when computer is in use?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was running a String vs StringBuilder test to explore Java GC and perhaps the JIT.

I noticed something peculiar. This graph, from 0 minutes to 2:31AM , my computer is basically doing nothing except for my Java program:

[image]

Then I started cursoring-around, opened a game, web browsing and suddenly the garbage collection gets much more agressive: (around 2:35AM)
[image]

Let's run the test again with Thread.sleep(1000):
[image]

This doesn't make any sense to me. Look at he allocated Heap in the first 2 graphs... no change. Is the JVM detecting that it's heap space may come under fire? When I look at my CPU, its putting along at the same 25% or less usage so there's no CPU bottleneck going on.
Then in the 3rd graph, it's deallocating heap much identically to when I am gaming and not gaming (using CPU is the point I'm trying to make here).

Why is this happening?

THE CODE if it could possible make a difference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        GCTests test = new GCTests();


        // Test setup
        int iterations = 1000;   // with 800MB


        // Keep running so I can see the results in jvisualm
        while(true) {



            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nSTARTING STRING TEST");
            test.withString(iterations);
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nALL DONE STRING TEST");
            Thread.sleep(20000);



            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nSTARTING STRINGBUILDER TEST");
            test.withStringBuilder(iterations);
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nALL DONE STRINGBUILDER TEST");
            Thread.sleep(20000);

        }

    }


    public void withString(int iterations) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        // Connect scanner to file
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\userx\\Desktop\\Intellij\\Practice\\DragNDrop\\src\\TextDragNDrop\\wordlist.10000.txt");
        Scanner in;



        // Append processed data to StringBuilder
        StringBuilder collectForOuput = new StringBuilder();
        String inputStr = "";   // Allow every line to consume one string


        //////// START iterationsIndex times loop ////////////
        // Trying to get millions of Strings being made
        int iterationsIndex = 0;
        while(iterationsIndex < iterations) {





            ///////// START FILE ///////////////////
            in = new Scanner(file);

            // Number of lines to expect and an index for each line
            int wordsCount = 10000;
            int wordCountIndex = 0;

            //in.nextLine();  // Consume newline

            while (wordCountIndex < wordsCount) {

                inputStr = in.nextLine();  // Assign to string, newline is consumed so need to do another
                // nextLine()

                for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i += 2) {

                    collectForOuput.append(inputStr.charAt(i));
                }
                collectForOuput.append(" ");
                for (int i = 1; i < inputStr.length(); i += 2) {

                    collectForOuput.append(inputStr.charAt(i));
                }
                collectForOuput.append("\n");

                wordCountIndex++;
            }
            //////// END FILE ///////////////////////////



            ////////////////////////
            // TEST PAUSE FOR GC ///
            ////////////////////////
            //Thread.sleep(1000);



            // File processed. Report and start again.
            iterationsIndex++;
            //System.out.println(iterationsIndex + " iterations complete.");

        }//////// END iterationsIndex times loop ////////////


        // At 1_000 iterations
        //System.out.println(collectForOuput.toString());

    }


    public void withStringBuilder(int iterations) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        // Connect scanner to file
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\userx\\Desktop\\Intellij\\Practice\\DragNDrop\\src\\TextDragNDrop\\wordlist.10000.txt");
        Scanner in;



        // Append processed data to StringBuilder
        StringBuilder collectForOuput = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder inputStr = new StringBuilder();    // Every line is appended to
                                                        // SB and SB is made length 0
                                                        // after every line is processes...


        //////// START iterationsIndex times loop ////////////
        // Trying to get millions of Strings being made
        int iterationsIndex = 0;
        while(iterationsIndex<iterations) {





            ///////// START FILE ///////////////////
            in = new Scanner(file);

            // Number of lines to expect and an index for each line
            int wordsCount = 10000;
            int wordCountIndex = 0;

            //in.nextLine();  // Consume newline

            while (wordCountIndex < wordsCount) {

                // Append to StringBuilder, newline is consumed so need to do another
                // nextLine()
                inputStr.append(in.nextLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i += 2) {

                    collectForOuput.append(inputStr.charAt(i));
                }
                collectForOuput.append(" ");
                for (int i = 1; i < inputStr.length(); i += 2) {

                    collectForOuput.append(inputStr.charAt(i));
                }
                collectForOuput.append("\n");
                inputStr.setLength(0);

                wordCountIndex++;
            }
            //////// END FILE ///////////////////////////



            ////////////////////////
            // TEST PAUSE FOR GC ///
            ////////////////////////
            //Thread.sleep(1000);



            // File processed. Report and start again.
            iterationsIndex++;
            //System.out.println(iterationsIndex + " iterations complete.");

        }//////// END iterationsIndex times loop ////////////


        // At 1_000 iterations
        //System.out.println(collectForOuput.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Did you repeat the experiment several times to ensure that this is a repeatable effect and not a spurious correlation?

Comment: @the8472 Yes sir. Over and over again, even with different Thread.sleep times , the used heap between both methods normalizes to the same (despite my assumptions). Also with system activity vs no system activity, these abberations defintiely occur when system activity begins!

Comment: @the8472 I've added a 3rd graph to support my question. If you have any clues, please post.

Comment: I'm going to come back to this later. WIll probably delete and re-post using simpler code.